# NPE when reading from directory Resource Stream

Tags: java, jar, classloader

I am trying to get a list of resource files in a resource directory from my jar file and hitting some strange behavior. The jar is loaded using a URLClassLoader which is loading 4 different .jar files.

I am doing the following :

```
    // Read the list of files from the resources/devices folder
    InputStream is = resourceClass.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myPackage/resources/devices");

    InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isReader);
    String str;

    try {
        str = reader.readLine();
     ...
```

When I run the application in the IDE from the .jar containing the resource everything works 100% as expected and I get the list of files from the folder in the .jar file. When I change (break) the path then "is" is null (in my app I of course check all these) and it returns safely.

When I however run it from the loading application OR from the command line the readLine throws a NPE.

I cannot explain this because in the debugger I can clearly see that "is" is not null (resource is found) and "isReader" and "reader" are also looking fine, so it seems like it is opening the stream just fine.

When the code is working I can see the bytes in the stream in the debugger, but when it NPE's I can see only blanks in the stream. Looking at permissions this seems to be fine, and besides it should not even return "is" if privilege were an issue.

So what is going on here? How do I figure out what is going on causing the NPE?

EDIT: Here is the full stack trace of the NPE.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
at com.microchip.mcc.mcu8.Mcu8PeripheralLibrary.getDeviceNameList(Mcu8PeripheralLibrary.java:47)
at com.microchip.mcc.mcu8.Mcu8PeripheralLibrary.getDevices(Mcu8PeripheralLibrary.java:27)
at com.microchip.mcc.core.service.BaseDeviceService.getDevices(BaseDeviceService.java:29)
at com.microchip.mcc.standalone.StandaloneViewer.populateDevices(StandaloneViewer.java:192)
at com.microchip.mcc.standalone.StandaloneViewer.initialize(StandaloneViewer.java:73)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:75)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:279)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2223)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2069)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2830)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2809)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2795)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2782)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2771)
at com.microchip.mcc.standalone.Standalone.start(Standalone.java:32)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:219)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:179)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:76)
```

Comment: `while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) { ... }` would at least avoid the NPE from the reader.

Comment: I have that. I tried to simplify the code to focus on the error at hand. reader is not null, I get a perfectly good reader with it's "in" internally being null. Makes no sense to me ...

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of your NPE ?

Comment: Did you verify the file path with `System.out.println(resourceClass.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myPackage/resources/devices"))`?

Comment: I have verified the paths and it is giving the correct path. I get the stream and everything looks perfect except that the stream seems to have no data in it !

Comment: Just to clarify, if the stream had no data in it that would be fine, I would expect readLn to return null, but that is not the case - it throws internally a NPE, which is entirely unexpected.